# How save data before ShutDown?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have the next requerments: If device was rebooted during process of calculation then app should continue calculations on boot completed from the same point where it was at point of device shutdown.So I would like to save my data before switching off phone. A am using Broadcast receiver. My broadcastReceiver should be triggered when the user switch off the phone. For this purpose I am using

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN);
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new ShutdownReceiver();
 registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

But I don't know how to put Extra data by this filter. So I thought it will be nice to use smt like this:

```
    shutdownIntent = new Intent(this,ShutdownReceiver.class);
    shutdownIntent.setAction(intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN);
    shutdownIntent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.progresStatus), value[0]);
```

But how to put this intent into receiver? Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android save app settings/data in Internal/External Storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119122/android-save-app-settings-data-in-internal-external-storage)

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using Service, which is doing some long calculation. So If the user switch off the phone I need to start calculation from previos point as soon as the phone will be switched on

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add extras to this `Intent`, because the `Intent` is being sent by Android. All you can do is listen for the `Intent`. If you need some data, then you should put that data in a shared preferences, which you can then read in `onReceive()`.