# android - read database from local file

Tags: android

I read and practice via article http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Here is my sample http://www.mediafire.com/?f8qbmummo0qeqnv

Some body can check and let me know why city table not found ? thanks

i have created a database with table

```
city : _id ; name
1 ; abc
2 ; def
```

and in DataNaseHelper.openDataBase i try

```
Cursor result = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM city", null);
                Log.d("trung", result.getExtras().toString());
```

But i get error

```
11-25 22:24:13.393: E/AndroidRuntime(337): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.joomavatar.phonebook/com.joomavatar.phonebook.NumberSearch}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: city: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM city
```

what is wrong here ?

```
 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        //The Android's default system path of your application database.
        private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.joomavatar.phonebook/databases/";

        private static final String DB_NAME = "hanoi";

        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

        private final Context myContext;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
         * @param context
         */
        public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            this.myContext = context;
        }   

      /**
         * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
         * */
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if(dbExist){
                //do nothing - database already exist
            }else{

                //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
                   //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {
                    Log.d("trung", "create table");
                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

        }

        /**
         * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
         * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
         */
        private boolean checkDataBase(){

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            }catch(SQLiteException e){

                //database does't exist yet.

            }

            if(checkDB != null){

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        /**
         * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
         * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
         * This is done by transfering bytestream.
         * */
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

            //Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            //Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

            //Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            Cursor result = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM city", null);
            Log.d("trung", result.getExtras().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

                if(myDataBase != null)
                    myDataBase.close();

                super.close();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

            // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
           // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
           // to you to create adapters for your views.

    }
```

Comment: check this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052262/cant-copy-sqlite-database-from-assets/8052459#8052459

Comment: Can you verify, that the db file is correctly copied to the internal memory? Does `/data/data/com.joomavatar.phonebook/databases/hanoi` exist?

Comment: yes , database exist, but don't search the city table. You can download my sample and check hanoi file in access folder. i don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

The table City is not found. In my opinion the best resource to learn about using SQlite
is

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: yes, i have try that tutorial. But in my case, i have a database file and i want load it. In my database, i have city table. But i get the above error and don't know why :(

Comment: Just to be sure that the database has been copied properly - can you export the database file from data/data folder and view it with some tool

Comment: huhhmmm.. it not run on emulator. I try on my htc device it work properly :D